# How can I make a div element float left after another float left while still filling the rest of the parent's width?

Tags: css

I am trying to figure out how to float these two elements after each other. The "square" element and the "wrapper" element while letting the "wrapper" element fill out the rest of the width of the parent element without giving it a fixed with because I don't know how much width it will have. The problem is also that the square element will have a dynamic width depending on the text inside it..

I have a simple html structure that looks like this:

```
<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="square">15103</div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="info">This is the info.</div>
    <div class="text">This is the text. Some very looong long text. It is not yet long but it will be long in about 20 seconds if we just keep going like this and let time fly by.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then some css:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.row {
  background: red;
}
.square {
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  background: gray;
}
.wrapper {
  float: left;
  background: blue;
}
.info {
  background: yellow;
}
.text {
  background: pink;
}
```

Here is the code on jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/1uoq9oej/3/

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you please try my answer, I have solved your issue. if you need I will update your fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove `float:left;` from `.wrapper` and add `margin-left: 20px`- it will make `.wrapper` flexible:

```css
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
 clear: both;
}
.row {
  background: red;
}
.square {
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: gray;
}
.wrapper {
  margin-left: 20px;
  background: blue;
}
.info {
  background: yellow;
}
.text {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="info">This is the info.</div>
    <div class="text">This is the text. Some very looong long text. It is not yet long but it will be long in about 20 seconds if we just keep going like this and let time fly by.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also do it with `flexbox` which is more modern:

```css
.row {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
}
.square {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: gray;
}
.wrapper {
  background: blue;
}
.info {
  background: yellow;
}
.text {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="info">This is the info.</div>
    <div class="text">This is the text. Some very looong long text. It is not yet long but it will be long in about 20 seconds if we just keep going like this and let time fly by.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And if you want to use `floats` and have `.square` with not fixed width, then you should add `overflow: hidden;` to `.wrapper` and it will float `.square` but will have remain width of the parent:

```css
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
 clear: both;
}
.row {
  background: red;
}
.square {
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  width: 30%;
  background: gray;
}
.wrapper {
  overflow:hidden;
  background: blue;
}
.info {
  background: yellow;
}
.text {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="info">This is the info.</div>
    <div class="text">This is the text. Some very looong long text. It is not yet long but it will be long in about 20 seconds if we just keep going like this and let time fly by.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the square will have dynamic width too depending on it's content. For example it might have a number like 15352. Then it will just float over if it has fixed width.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please change your css with the following :-

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.row {
  background: red;
  display: inline-flex;
}
.square {
  float: left;
  background: gray;
  display:inline-block;
}
.wrapper {
  float: left;
  background: blue;
  display:inline-block;
}
.info {
  background: yellow;
}
.text {
  background: pink;
}
```

It solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css code in your fiddle. Should fix the issue.

```
.row {
  background: red;
}
.square {
  height: 20px;
  background: gray;
}
.wrapper {
  background: blue;
}
.info {
  background: yellow;
}
.text {
  background: pink;
}

.wrapper,
.square {
  display: table-cell;
}

.clearfix {
  display: table;
}
```